# How to detect if video file is pure static?

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, imagemagick

I have a collection of analog video recordings. About 10% of the files are entirely static. How could I programmatically look at all files and delete the files that contain mostly static?

The following utilities have command line options to analyze video, however none have built in functionality to detect the absence of video content.

1. ffmpeg
2. ffprobe
3. HandBrake

I've tried using ffmpeg to export still images and then use [image magick](https://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php) to compare the difference between those images. Unfortunately, the difference between an image of static, and actual video content returns nearly the same difference percentage. (9% vs 7%)

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:30 -i PICT0050.AVI -vframes 1 -q:v 2 output1.jpg

magick compare -metric PSNR output1.jpg output2.jpg diff.jpg
9.2191

magick compare -metric PSNR output1.jpg output3.jpg diff.jpg
7.70127
```

Comparing sample 1 with sample 2 results in 9% difference
Comparing sample 1 with sample 3 results in 7% difference

Sample 1
[image]

Sample 2
[image]
Sample 3
[image]
Sample 4
[image]
Sample 5
[image]
Sample 6
[image]
Sample 7
[image]

Comment: Share a couple of samples of both types.

Comment: Do you mean image samples or video samples? I've added more image samples.

Comment: Video samples..

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the static images are black and white without any colour - so I would look at the mean saturation and if it is low/zero, I would assume they are static. So, in `bash` and assuming your images are named `sampleXXX.jpg`:

```
for f in sample*jpg; do 
    convert "$f" -colorspace HSL -channel S -separate -format '%M avg sat=%[fx:int(mean*100)]\n' info:
done
```

**Sample Output**

```
sample1.jpg avg sat=0
sample2.jpg avg sat=0
sample3.jpg avg sat=21
sample4.jpg avg sat=0
sample5.jpg avg sat=39
sample6.jpg avg sat=31
```

which suggests that samples 1,2 and 4 are static.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to look at the amount of edges using Imagemagick to rank the amount of noise. The noise images will have more edges.

```
for img in *; do
edginess=`convert $img -edge 1 -scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:mean]" info:`
echo "$img $edginess"
done

1bidV.jpg 0.0472165
3FJUJ.jpg 0.275502  <---- noise image
QpQvA.jpg 0.332296  <---- noise image
b4Gxy.jpg 0.0428422
gQcXP.jpg 0.0437578
vF1YZ.jpg 0.322911  <---- noise image
```